# cmake: build dependency downloaded with ExternalProject_Add before hand

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to get my test program `main.cpp` to link against a an externally downloaded library (in this case `fmt 8.1.1`) via `cmake`'s 'ExternalProject_Add' function as follows

##### `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)

project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(fmt
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt.git
        GIT_TAG 8.1.1
        CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=20 -DFMT_TEST=OFF -DFMT_DOC=OFF -DFMT_INSTALL=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/fmt-build
        STEP_TARGETS build
        )
set(fmt_BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/fmt-prefix/src/fmt-build")
set(fmt_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/fmt-prefix/src/fmt/include")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} fmt-build) # does not have an effect
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${fmt_BINARY_DIR}/libfmt.a)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${fmt_SOURCE_DIR})
```

##### `main.cpp`

```
#include <chrono>
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/chrono.h>

int main() {
    const auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    fmt::print("The time is {}", now);
    return 0;
}
```

The test program `main.cpp` runs OK *if* I build the target `fmt-build` before hand, but complains that

```
ninja: error: 'fmt-prefix/src/fmt-build/libfmt.a', needed by 'test', missing and no known rule to make it
```

indicating that the dependency `fmt-build` must be built before hand. While that's doable, how do I get `cmake` to autmoatically build `fmt-build` as a dependency for `test` without haing to run it manually first? I thought the line `add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} fmt-build)` should take care of that but evidently it does not.

Comment: When Ninja is used as a build system, target-level dependency alone is not sufficient for express dependencies between files. Every generated file should be noted either as OUTPUT for a custom command or as a "byproduct" for a target. In case of `ExternalProject_Add`, there is BUILD_BYPRODUCTS option which specifies byproducts for a built step. You need to specify the library file in that option.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what @Tsyvarev commented, simply adding the line

```
BUILD_BYPRODUCTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/fmt-prefix/src/fmt-build/libfmt.a
```

to the `ExternalProject_Add` call does the trick, and one does not have to manually build `fmt-build` before hand.